# Sending email from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, email

I'm writing a user registration process in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC, and I'd like to send a confirmation email to the user during that process.  I know I can do this using the classes in the `System.Net.Mail` namespace, but I have a few questions on the best way to implement this.

1. Before I go down the path of writing my own code to send email, are there any existing solutions like [ActionMailer](http://am.rubyonrails.org/) for ASP.NET MVC?
2. If I do roll my own, should I do this on the web server during the request and would using [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx) bog down the web server, tying up threads as they wait on the SMTP server to respond?  If so, would [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) be preferable?
3. Would it be better pull this out of ASP.NET MVC entirely, maybe by writing a record to a database table and having a windows service periodically sweep the table and send out the messages?

At the moment, I am leaning towards #3, since that would give me the flexibility of doing this work on another server entirely, but was wondering what others are doing.  Are there options and/or issues I haven't considered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would agree that #3 is your best option.  It's the most complex of the three, but none of them are terribly complex.  What it does do, however, is:

1. Give you a record of all emails sent by the system.
2. Remove the dependency of the email system from the live application.  (Separation of concerns is always fun.)
3. Provide a natural re-try mechanism when the email system dependency is failing.

As for an existing library for making the creation/sending of the `MailMessage` objects easier, I've never seen a need.  If you're just sending the messages to an SMTP server, the built-in objects are more than adequate and easy to use.

Comment: #3 would be the best and I've done it many projects. However, everytime I use that solution, I can't help but feel a little silly for writing a queue for a SMTP queue  :)

Comment: @Naren: I once implemented #3 where the application would send the mail message to the data service by means of a message queue.  After all, what's another layer of abstraction among services?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. Problem arises when you have a fresh dev trying to follow the message trail :) or when that fresh dev is YOU! :)

Answer (score 3):

MvcMailer is like an ActionMailer for .Net. See the NuGet package [here](http://nuget.org/Packages/Search?packageType=Packages&searchCategory=All+Categories&searchTerm=mvcmailer) and the [project documentation](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This would, IMO, be the cleanest solution.  You can either use the View as the message body OR specify the message body manually, but there is nothing more than one line of code really to perform the Send.  Nice find!